# How to limit SmartThings Lock to prevent accidental unlock?

Tags: smart-home, security, samsung-smartthings, home-security

I have a Schlage Connect Z-Wave door lock. I can control it via my SmartThings App but I do not feel secure knowing that someone who hacked my account or my phone can easily gain access to my home.

In addition, the lock/unlock button can be pressed accidentally w/o any confirmation dialog. My deadbolt can be flaky and once unlocked, it could be stuck and not be able to lock again.

I am wondering if there is a way to limit the smart lock to allow only lock but not unlock?

Comment: Interesting thought, only providing the lock functionality would certainly be good from a security perspective.

Comment: In my opinion, the smartphone app specification needs to factor in disabling of unlock button or protect unlock with a paraphrase. OR the manufacturer needs to provide a physical button, such that when it is pressed the app unlock won't work

Answer (score 3):

No.  Your goals and concerns contradict with each other:

> My deadbolt can be flaky and once unlocked, it could be stuck and not be able to lock again.

Points out that the goal of

> I am wondering if there is a way to limit the smart lock to allow only lock but not unlock?

Is not meaningfully achievable, since the "lock" attempt might not actually accomplish anything.

You would need a system-rengineering to report the lock status by a means you consider reliable.

Or you could just add an additional mechanical deadbolt and only use the IoT system for temporary convenience purposes.

To make the system only able to lock and not unlock, you could probably do something like disconnect one coil (if there is a distinct coil for each direction) or enforce a polarity with a diode (in the less likely situation that a polarized coil is used with a magnet, or the more likely case that a motor is used).

Comment: No contradictions. Here is a scenario: Checking door using App => door was locked => accidentally pressed "lock" button => door unlocked => press "unlock" button again to lock => failed. Panic!

Comment: How do you know the door was locked to begin with?  If it was because you manually locked or checked it, then the proposed lock-only IoT capability is gaining you nothing.  If you used the IoT capability to "lock" it, it is as likely to have failed at that attempt as to have failed to re-lock after the initial lock.

Comment: I don't understand your logic. The app tells me my door is locked, I don't want to accidentally unlock the lock by tapping it. Is it so hard to understand?

Comment: You claim that the deadbolt can silently fail to lock, therefore either the app cannot reliably tell you that the door is locked, or your premise that it can silently fail to lock without notice is false!

Comment: I did not claim "the deadbolt can *silently* fail to lock".